# Azure Chrono Trigger Notation Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create a chrono trigger to run an Azure function at 11pm, 12am, 1am, 2am, 3am, and 4am on the hour.  I'm using the following notation: `0 0 23,0,1,2,3,4 * * *` but my Function never runs.

I've changed it to different individual times, eg `0 0 23 * * *` and `0 0 1 * * *` and everything fires off okay.

Another strange behavior I noticed is when I change it to `0 0 23-3 * * *`, my Function will run every hour OUTSIDE the range 23HR-03HR.

Does anyone know what's could be causing this behavior? Could there be an issue with time ranges in Azure wrapping from one day into the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could there be an issue with time ranges in Azure wrapping from one day into the next?

Hour ranges that cross over midnight are not supported and are interpreted the other way round.

Azure Functions uses the [NCronTab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) library to interpret NCRONTAB expressions. Checking its issues, I found [ranges that cross over midnight](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/issues/24) and [Hour semantics](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/issues/14).

> *Is it possible to provide a range that crosses over midnight (e.g. 21-5)?*
> No, that's the same as 5-21.

Not tested, but what if you use the notation `0 0 0,1,2,3,4,23 * * *`?

Comment: That notation works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the value `23` with the range `0-4`, like this:

```
0 0 23,0-4 * * *
```

As @rickvdbosch stated in their answer, Azure Functions uses NCronTab to intrepret cron expressions. There are sites you can use to test NCronTab expressions, such as https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/.